# Cross-domain access to SSAS

Tags: cross-domain, ssas, windows-authentication

Our IT department has set up a sandbox server for developers on a separate network.  It is running SQL Server 2008 R2, and Sharepoint Enterprise 2010 with PowerPivot, which requires Analysis Services (SSAS).

We wish to access the analysis server via PowerPivot for Excel and also through VS 2008 BIDS. We can get data into Excel PowerPivot from the relational database because we have SQL Server Authentication accounts set up with the database engine.

To publish PowerPivot results to SharePoint, however (and to do analysis in BIDS) we would presumably need to access the Analysis Services server.  We were surprised to learn that SSAS only supports windows authentication.  Of course, this isn't working because our Windows accounts are in a separate network domain.

Is there a way, using Active Directory, HTTP via IIS, or any other mechanism, that we can access the SSAS server from our local machines?

Answer (score 2):

You can access SSAS over a HTML pump:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917711.aspx

The article is for SQL2005, but I'm positive it would work similarly with your version.

Answer (score 2):

Not the best solution, but if you create a Windows user in the sandbox network, using the same username/password as your AD login, it should work.

Answer (score 2):

you might also want to try runas with the netonly option:

http://www.markwilson.co.uk/blog/2008/03/the-windows-runas-command-and-the-netonly-switch.htm